# making readFile a function in c

Tags: c

I want to use `readFile` as function but i'm not sure what to fill in for arguments:

```
void readFile(){
    FILE *cfPtr = NULL;

    char list[SIZEA][SIZEB];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    cfPtr = fopen("unsorted.txt","r");
        while (fgets(list[i], SIZEA, cfPtr)) {
            list[i][strlen(list[i]) - 1] = '\0';
            i++;
}

    j = i;
        for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
            printf("%s\n", list[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: What data do you want to pass to the function? They will be the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally depends on your requirement. However, as per my understanding you can pass following parameters.

```
void readFile(const cahr * filename, const char *mode)
```